# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in xamarin ios app group

Tags: ios, xamarin, widget

I am trying to build today widget in Xamarin.
In the simulator everything works, but when I run it on real device my widget crashes with the following exception:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code is:

```
var defs = new NSUserDefaults("group.com.gto.extension", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
defs.Synchronize(); 

var equities = defs.ValueForKey(new NSString("key1"));--> this row crashes my widget.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in-between trying to access the `NSUserDefaults` for a single application or a group hereof. The latter is what you are currently trying to achieve. I will try to summaries the difference between the two strategies in this answer.

## App Group User Defaults

I assume you're trying to read an entry from the `NSUserDefaults` from another application or extension you have made? Only in that case it is sensible to use the `NSUserDefaults` of the given. If so, you need to ensure the following:

> First, you will need to ensure that the App Group and the required App IDs have been properly configured in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section on iOS Dev Center and have been installed on in the development environment.
>
> Next, your App and/or Extension projects will need to be one of the valid App IDs created above, that the Entitlements.plist file has the App Groups enabled and specified and that it get's included in the App Bundle.
>
> With this all in place, the shared App Group user Defaults can be accessed [...]
>
> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/user-defaults/#Accessing_an_App_Group_NSUserDefaults_Instance

The two points mentioned above may be the reason to why your application is crashing.

## Single-application User Defaults

If on the other hand you only need to access a value from the `NSUserDefaults` of the current application, you can simply do as follows:

```
var defs = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
```

## Reading the values

To read values from the `NSUserDefaults`, as seen in the [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/user-defaults/) and [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSUserDefaults/), you should do as follows:

```
var boolForKey = defs.BoolForKey("key");
var stringForKey = defs.StringForKey("key");
....
```

Where `"key"` parameter is the `key` for the `value` you previously stored in your `NSUserDefaults` dictionary.

It would most likely also be sensible to surround any calls to retrieve values from the `NSUserDefaults` in a try/catch. The `key` may not yet exist in the `NSUserDefaults`, which is most likely the issue in your case.

Comment: Can you tell me why xamarin uses:                                                            var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

var useHeader = plist.BoolForKey("UseHeader");

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it will provide more clarification.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to solve my issue. I've surrounded the code with try/ catch and realized that it takes time to update key in AppGroup. Once updated, I can see the result.

Comment: You are welcome. Some error handling is always a good idea. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. That would also help me :)